# i get this error Must declare the scalar variable "@"

Tags: vb.net

Here is the code:

Private Sub Button5_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click

```
    con = New SqlConnection("Data Source=LAPTOP-16IIQENS\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=students;Integrated Security=True")
        con.Open()
    cmd = New SqlCommand("select * from data where [Roll No.]=@[Roll No.]", con)
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Roll No.", SqlDbType.Int).Value = TextBox5.Text
    Dim adp As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
        Dim table As New DataTable()
    adp.Fill(table)
    If (table.Rows.Count() > 0) Then
            DataGridView1.DataSource = table
            TextBox2.Text = table.Rows(0)(0).ToString
            TextBox1.Text = table.Rows(0)(1).ToString
            TextBox3.Text = table.Rows(0)(2).ToString
            TextBox4.Text = table.Rows(0)(3).ToString
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("No Data Found")

        End If


End Sub
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CHNFN.png)

Comment: You should generally avoid spaces and other special characters in your database table and column names in the first place. They just make it more likely that you'll encounter issues later. Just use names like `RollNo` or, better `RollNumber`. There's usually little point to abbreviating these days, as it reduces clarity while offering little benefit when modern development tools mean that you rarely have to type the whole thing. If you need something more user-friendly in the UI then add that to the UI specifically.

Answer (score 2):

You can freely choose the name of your SQL parameter, it does not need to match the name of the field.

Thus, if you call your parameter `@RollNo` instead of `@Roll No.` (no space, no dot), you no longer need to escape the name in your SQL, which should fix your current issue.

Change:

```
cmd = New SqlCommand("select * from data where [Roll No.]=@[Roll No.]", con)
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Roll No.", SqlDbType.Int).Value = TextBox5.Text
```

to:

```
cmd = New SqlCommand("select * from data where [Roll No.]=@RollNo", con)
cmd.Parameters.Add("@RollNo", SqlDbType.Int).Value = TextBox5.Text
```

Comment: It Worked Tons Of Love dude

Comment: When you pass parameter always use without space for double word or give underscore between 2 word and also don't use any other special characters also. 
Try like this RollNo or Roll_No